# Delete all files/folders from within a directory

Tags: command-line, delete

I have navigated to the desired folder in my command window and I would like to delete all files and folders within the specific directory where I am currently located. I do **not** want to delete any files/folders outside of this directory.

How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: damn I even answered that one @pomsky :D

Answer (score 10):

`rm -r /path/to/dir/*`

- `- r`  is for deleting also subdirectories
- `*`   is for selecting all the files in the directory

Comment: This is the safest answer.

Comment: how would this deal with sub-folders inside `/path/to/dir/` ?

Answer (score 4):

Use the command:

```
rm -rf *
```

So far your in the desired folder that should remove all that's there.

`-r`: recursive or move into any directory in that location

`-f`: ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt

`*`: all the contents of that location

Comment: Your second example is potentially dangerous, 'cause if they place a space between the . and the /, or leave out the ., they'll wipe out root.